# Powershell List of Files Remove Item Check if Fails

Tags: powershell

I have very simple Powershell script which has deleting list of files.

However sometimes although it fails script behaves as success.

I'm trying to implement to check if file exist after removal process.

So we will understand it works or not.

However I could not run the script correctly.

`powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "Get-Content 'Silinecekler-Listesi.txt' | ForEach-Object { $_ | Remove-Item -Recurse -whatif if (Test-Path $_){ Write-Output 'Fail' $_ } }"`

Where Am I wrong

Comment: Looks like you need a `;` between `-whatif` and `if (`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you for your reply. Now it works. However does not check for files which is not deleted. Forexample locked files.